# Como comvertir una imagen a base 64 - Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, vuetify

Hola tengo este tema que espero me puedan ayudar

Tengo un proyecto en vue js con vuetify la cual e hecho una pagina donde se adjuntan fotos, hasta ahi lo tengo hecho y funciona todo onkeydown
Pero ahora quiero convertir esa imagen a base64, alguna sugerencia?

Les comparto el codigo que tengo.

```
**<template>
  <div>
    <v-file-input 
      @change="Preview_image"
      v-model="image"
      >
    </v-file-input>
    <v-img :src="url"></v-img>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  data: () =>({
    url: null,
    image: null,

    
  }),
  methods: {
    Preview_image() {
      this.url= URL.createObjectURL(this.image)
    }
  }
}
</script>**
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: this.image es un File?

Comment: Hola, soy un poco nuevo en esto, me reporta una especie de enlace la cual se almacena en esa variable   **blob:http://localhost:8080/5555106d-b876-4e4d-ae6b-a68fa0be5bb2**  este enlace es el que se manda a la propiedad src de la etiqueta <v-img/>